# Stuck on nasty integral regarding associated Legendre polynomials and spherical Bessel functions.

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, legendre-functions

I'm preparing notes for an undergrad physics course I'm going to be teaching soon. Unfortunately, this sort of stuff was taught to me only in a very handwavy sort of way ("you take these physical principles and these equations and then skip over a bunch of maths and you eventually get here"). I do realise why it is done in such a way, as the maths are pretty dense (for an undergrad, anyway) and the result is what's important, but, well, I've always had a soft spot for mathematical rigour.

Without further ado, here's where I'm stuck: I'm trying to show that
$$\int_0^\pi e^{i\rho\cos(\theta)}\left(\cos(\theta)\,\frac{\text{d}P_\ell^1\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{\text{d}\theta}+\frac{P_\ell^1\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{\sin(\theta)}\right)\sin(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta = \frac{2\ell(\ell+1)}{\rho}\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\rho}\left(\rho j_\ell(\rho)\right),$$
where $P_\ell^1$ is the associated Legendre function of order $_\ell^1$ and $j_\ell$ is the spherical Bessel function of the first kind of order $\ell$. (In case anyone is interested, the above is equation 4.35 of Bohren C F & Huffman D R (1983): *Absorption and scattering of light by small particles*, Wiley. I've been following that book for this part of the course, and this is the first time I've been this stuck.)

I've been trying to use the identities
$$\int_0^\pi\left(P_\ell^m\left(\cos(\theta)\right)\right)^2\sin(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta = \frac{2(\ell+m)!}{(2\ell+1)(\ell-m)!},\\
\int_{-1}^1\frac{P_\ell^m(x)^2}{1-x^2}\,\text{d}x = \frac{(\ell+m)!}{m(\ell-m)!},\\
2i^\ell j_\ell(\rho) = \int_0^\pi e^{i\rho\cos(\theta)}P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)\sin(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta,$$
where $P_\ell$ is the Legendre polynomial of order $\ell$ and is equal to $P_\ell^0$ by definition of the $P_\ell^m$. (Obviously the third one has to be used at some point; the others might or might not be, but I've tried using them.)

I've also tried using the relationship
$$P_\ell^1\left(\cos(\theta)\right) = \frac{\text{d}P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{\text{d}\theta}$$
and the fact that the $P_\ell^m$ satisfy the differential equation
$$\frac{\text{d}^2 P_\ell^m\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{\text{d}\theta^2}+\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\,\frac{\text{d}P_\ell^m\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{\text{d}\theta}+\left(\ell(\ell+1)-\frac{m^2}{\sin^2(\theta)}\right)P_\ell^m\left(\cos(\theta)\right) = 0$$
(and the $P_\ell$ satisfy that with $m=0$).

I've tried integrating by parts, combining the above identities in different ways, using some of the various recurrence relations between the $P_\ell^m$ and between the $P_\ell$ and between the $j_\ell$... but, as I've said, after a whole week of dealing with that one integral, I'm still stuck.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tthe associated Legendre polynomials are first converted into Legendre polynomials,
\begin{align}
 I(\rho)&=\int_0^\pi e^{i\rho\cos(\theta)}\left(\cos(\theta)\,\frac{dP_\ell^1\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}+\frac{P_\ell^1\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{\sin(\theta)}\right)\sin(\theta)\,d\theta \\
 &=\int_0^\pi e^{i\rho\cos(\theta)}\left(\cos(\theta)\,\frac{d^2P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta^2}+\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\frac{dP_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)\sin(\theta)\,d\theta
\end{align}
From the Legendre differential equation given in the OP (with $m=0$),
we have
\begin{equation}
 \frac{d^2 P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta^2}+\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\,\frac{dP_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}+\ell(\ell+1)P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right) = 0
\end{equation}
and thus
\begin{align}
 \cos(\theta)&\,\frac{d^2P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta^2}+\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\frac{dP_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\\
 &=\sin(\theta)\frac{dP_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}-\ell(\ell+1)\cos(\theta)P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{equation}
 I(\rho)=\int_0^\pi e^{i\rho\cos(\theta)}\left(  \sin(\theta)\frac{dP_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}-\ell(\ell+1)\cos(\theta)P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)\right)\sin(\theta)\,d\theta
\end{equation}
Now, by changing $x=\cos\theta$, with $\frac{dP_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}=-\sin\theta\frac{dP_\ell(x)}{dx}$
\begin{equation}
 I(\rho)=\int_{-1}^1e^{i\rho x}\left( (x^2-1)\frac{dP_\ell(x)}{dx}- \ell(\ell+1)xP_\ell\left(x\right)\right)\,dx
\end{equation}
From the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Recurrence_relations)
\begin{equation}
 \frac {x^{2}-1}{n}\frac {d}{dx}P_{n}(x)=xP_{n}(x)-P_{n-1}(x)
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
 I(\rho)=-\int_{-1}^1e^{i\rho x}\left(\ell P_{\ell-1}(x)+ \ell^2xP_\ell\left(x\right)\right)\,dx
\end{equation}
and from the given spherical Bessel function relation,
\begin{align}
2i^\ell j_\ell(\rho) &= \int_0^\pi e^{i\rho\cos(\theta)}P_\ell\left(\cos(\theta)\right)\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{-1}^1e^{i\rho x}P_{\ell}(x)\,dx\\
2i^{\ell-1}\frac{dj_{\ell}(\rho)}{d\rho}&=\int_{-1}^1e^{i\rho x}xP_{\ell}(x)\,dx
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{equation}
 I(\rho)=-2i^{\ell-1}\ell j_{\ell-1}(\rho)-\ell^22i^{\ell-1}\frac{dj_{\ell}(\rho)}{d\rho}
\end{equation}
One of the [recurrence relations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.51.E2) for the spherical Bessel functions reads
\begin{equation}
 j_{n}^{\prime}(z)=j_{n-1}(z)-((n+1)/z)j_{n}(z)
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{align}
 I(\rho)&=-2i^{\ell-1}\ell(\ell+1)\left( \frac1\rho j_\ell(\rho)+\frac{dj_\ell(\rho)}{d\rho} \right)\\
 &=\frac{-2i^{\ell-1}\ell(\ell+1)}{\rho}\frac{d}{d\rho}\left( \rho j_\ell(\rho) \right)
\end{align}
This result, which seems to be numerically correct, is different from the proposed one by a factor of $-i^{\ell-1}$. For $\ell$ even, the present result shos that the integral is purely imaginary as is expected, contrarily to the proposed identity. Could the discrepancy be related to a particular choice of the branch cut for the Legendre function?

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I have no idea how you managed to do all of that. :) I just followed your steps carefully and got the same result as you. I wouldn't be surprised if the book were wrong; it's a great resource for learning and one of my favourite optics textbooks, but it wouldn't be the first mistake I come across.